# How to use jQuery Isotope in dir=rtl

Tags: javascript, user-interface, jquery-isotope

how do I align an [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) layout right-to-left to follow the document direction (dir=rtl).

Comment: Just remove the 1562th character.

Comment: I have no idea what you are even asking here

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Isotope has a config option which should be set so that is anchored to the right

```
{
    isOriginLeft: false
}
```

[the example from the documentation](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/gadFJ)